# TypeError: Failed to construct 'URL': Invalid URL when using NextAuth.js credentials provider with redirect set to false

Tags: typescript, next-auth, next.js13

Title:
TypeError: Failed to construct 'URL': Invalid URL when using NextAuth.js credentials provider with redirect set to false

Question:
I'm currently working on a Next.js 13 application (with app directory) that utilizes NextAuth.js for authentication, Prisma for database operations, and PlanetScale as the database provider. I have encountered an error when using the NextAuth.js credentials provider and setting signIn options to {redirect: false}.

When I attempt to log in with correct credentials using the credentials provider, I receive the following error:

```
TypeError: Failed to construct 'URL': Invalid URL
    at _callee6$ (webpack-internal:///(app-client)/./node_modules/next-auth/react/index.js:337:21)
    at tryCatch (webpack-internal:///(app-client)/./node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/regeneratorRuntime.js:44:17)
    at Generator.eval (webpack-internal:///(app-client)/./node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/regeneratorRuntime.js:125:22)
    at Generator.eval [as next] (webpack-internal:///(app-client)/./node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/regeneratorRuntime.js:69:21)
    at asyncGeneratorStep (webpack-internal:///(app-client)/./node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/asyncToGenerator.js:3:24)
    at _next (webpack-internal:///(app-client)/./node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/asyncToGenerator.js:22:9)
```

Here's an example of my code setup:

```
// auth.ts

const authOptions: NextAuthOptions = {
  adapter: PrismaAdapter(db),
  session: {
    strategy: 'jwt',
  },
  pages: {
    signIn: '/login',
  },
  providers: [
    GoogleProvider({
      clientId: envVariables.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: envVariables.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
    }),
    Credentials({
      name: 'credentials',
      credentials: {
        email: {
          label: 'email',
          type: 'email',
          placeholder: 'wantnewstyle@mail.com',
        },
        password: {
          label: 'password',
          type: 'password',
        },
      },
      async authorize(credentials) {
        if (!credentials) {
          throw new Error('Грешни данни');
        }
        const dbUser = await db.user.findFirst({
          where: {
            email: credentials.email,
          },
        });

        if (!dbUser) {
          throw new Error('Грешен имейл');
        }

        // Check if passwords match
        const checkPassword = await bcrypt.compare(
          credentials.password,
          dbUser?.password ?? ''
        );

        if (!checkPassword) {
          throw new Error('Грешна парола');
        }
        return dbUser;
      },
    }),
  ],
  callbacks: {
    session({ token, session }) {
      if (token) {
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-param-reassign
        session.user.id = token.id;
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-param-reassign
        session.user.name = token.name;
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-param-reassign
        session.user.firstName = token.firstName;
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-param-reassign
        session.user.lastName = token.lastName;
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-param-reassign
        session.user.phone = token.phone;
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-param-reassign
        session.user.email = token.email;
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-param-reassign
        session.user.image = token.picture;
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-param-reassign
        session.user.isBarber = token.isBarber;
      }

      return session;
    },

    async jwt({ token, user }) {
      const dbUser = await db.user.findFirst({
        where: {
          email: token.email,
        },
        include: {
          barber: true,
        },
      });

      if (!dbUser) {
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-param-reassign
        token.id = user!.id;
        return token;
      }

      return {
        id: dbUser.id,
        firstName: dbUser.firstName!,
        lastName: dbUser.lastName!,
        email: dbUser.email,
        picture: dbUser.image,
        phone: dbUser.phone!,
        isBarber: dbUser.barber !== null,
      };
    },
    redirect() {
      return '/';
    },
  },
};

export default authOptions;
```

```
// login-form.tsx
async function onSubmit(values: z.infer<typeof loginSchema>) {
    const result = await signIn('credentials', {
      email: values.email,
      password: values.password,
      redirect: false,
    });

    if (result?.error === 'Грешен имейл') {
      form.setError('email', {
        message: result.error,
      });
      return;
    }

    if (result?.error === 'Грешна парола') {
      form.setError('password', {
        message: result.error,
      });
      return;
    }

    await wait(3000);
    redirect('/');
  }
}
```

I would greatly appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to troubleshoot and fix this issue. Thank you in advance!

Comment: I am facing the issue  and already spent days to figure out but still not able to solve. I guess the auth.ts code is from Josh tried coding Reddit clone tutorial? I used exactly the same code but added credentials login.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue while using credentials provider with redirect set to false in the signIn  function. Solved this by passing the complete redirect url in the redirect callback instead of giving a relative path. In auth.ts where the redirect callback is defined try something like this :

```
callbacks: {
  async redirect({ url, baseUrl }) {
    if (url.startsWith("/")) return `${baseUrl}${url}`
    return baseUrl
  }
}
```

I suppose it always uses the redirect url even if we set redirect to false. You can find additional details in their documentation on callback configurations.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by upgrading to 5.0.0-beta.5